# When to execute text (.txt) file and python (.py) file simultaneously in cmd and why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to develop a text based adventure game, but in my question file there is a line like this:

```
> python textGame.py gameConfiguration.txt
```

which prints:

```
Welcome to the house game!
You are in the Hall.
```

I don't know why the text file and python file are executed simultaneously.

I have searched lot about this process but I couldn't find a satisfactory answer. If someone knows about this execution could you explain this with an example, if possible?

Comment: As you claimed **you** wrote that program, you should already know how this works. As you don't, it very much looks like you just got the code somewhere and try to cheat your homework.

Comment: Looks like I hit a nerve. Just [be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)

Answer (score 2):

The python interpreter **never** executes multiple files simultaneously. It handles its first argument differently from the other argument. The first argument (*textGame.py*) is the **file** that is going to be executed. The following argument (*gameConfiguration.txt*) is passed as an argument to the python program. See `python -h`

`usage: python [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...`

A python program can access its arguments via *sys.argv*.
[This article](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/argv/more-fun-with-sys-argv) explains how to use sys.argv.

Answer (score 1):

The `.txt` file isn't executing, it's a command line argument to the Python script. Presumably the script needs to load configuration from said file. Every command line program has different required arguments (and often optional switches as well); this one happens to need a text configuration file.

When a Python script runs, it receives the command line in `sys.argv`, and can use it in arbitrary ways (in this case, likely opening the file, reading it, and using it to configure the game).